# Exporting array object to file in JSON format

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project. i have gathered data into an array and i can currently download it into a csv format through an angular package but i cannot find a package that will download the same data into a JSON format should my client wish to do so. is there a way to download an array object to a file in JSON format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about array of objects which you want to download as a josn file then you can go with file-saver.

1. install file saver `npm install file-saver --save`
2. for typescript definitions, install `npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev`
3. inside your .ts just import: `import { saveAs } from "file-saver";`

Note: no need to import the module in app.module.ts, you can directly import the point no. 3 in your ts wherever required

4. Finally add below code to download json file

   ```
   exportTojson() {
   // exportData is your array which you want to dowanload as json and sample.json is your file name, customize the below lines as per your need.
   let exportData = this.users;
   return saveAs(
     new Blob([JSON.stringify(exportData, null, 2)], { type: 'JSON' }), 'sample.json'
   );}
   ```
5. For more details [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

Comment: this does work as it gives me a json file downloaded but its just and file full of empty arrays.

Comment: Have you cross checked if the array you are passing consists of data? can you please provide the code snippet if possible for better understanding.

Comment: yes. i did a console log of the exportData and it matches my dataObj array. just when putting it through the stringify it seems to remove all the data and prints empty []

Comment: `let exportData = this.dataObj;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(exportData, null, 2))`

printing out: `[],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],`

Comment: can you show the structure of this.dataObj? may be with some sample data

Comment: this.dataObj = `0: [STATION: '72399014711', DATE: '2021-05-30', TIME: '00:56:00', LATITUDE: '40.1962', LONGITUDE: '-76.77249', …]
1: [STATION: '72399014711', DATE: '2021-05-30', TIME: '01:56:00', LATITUDE: '40.1962', LONGITUDE: '-76.77249', …]
2: [STATION: '72399014711', DATE: '2021-05-30', TIME: '02:56:00', LATITUDE: '40.1962', LONGITUDE: '-76.77249', …]` etc

Comment: ok let me check, will update you

Comment: is your this.dataObj: any = {} ? not able to understand the structure of this.dataObj, how you have declared that?

Comment: yes i have it declared as dataObj: any[] = [];

Comment: I'm facing issue while assigning dataObj, can you create a stackblitz ?

Comment: took me a minute. had to literally copy everything. also its giving me an error with the file-saver on stack-blitz but heres the link: https://angular-ivy-ynheeg.stackblitz.io

Comment: the code you gave me is in the display.component.ts file

Comment: i got it to work. thanks!! marking answer as correct

Comment: Glad that helped you, the link you have shared is not working for me